# Open/Close braces / brackets : highlight the lines that connect them in Sublime

Tags: sublimetext2

I miss a nice feature of Notepad++ which was connecting the opening and closing line of a function/bracket with a highlighted line. Sublime connects them too, but the dotted line doesn't change color...
[image]

Comment: Can you put a screenshot of the Notepad++ feature?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [BracketHighlighter](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter). With a little configuration, I think it will give you what you want. Specifically the [Configuring Highlighting Style](https://github.com/facelessuser/BracketHighlighter#configuring-highlight-style) section.

Steps after installing BracketHighlighter...


From **Preferences -> Browse Packages...** create a file called bh_core.sublime-settings in your **User** folder.


Add the following code:

```
{
  "content_highlight_bar": true,
  "align_content_highlight_bar": true,
}
```

[Here is the section you are looking for!](http://facelessuser.github.io/BracketHighlighter/customize/#content_highlight_bar)